# is there is any way to get the width and height of a resizable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is there is any way to get the width and height of a resizable div while resizing i try the following code but it resulted as undefined in alert box
i am using jQuery resizable

```
$("#msc_div").resizable({
     start: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        alert(offset.height);
        alert(offset.width);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#msc_div").resizable({
    start: function() {

        var t = $(this);

        alert( t.height() );
        alert( t.width() );

    }
});
```

See:

- **http://api.jquery.com/height/**
- **http://api.jquery.com/width/**

Comment: +1 One of the most extensive answers I've seen so far (at least from the ones having the jQuery tag).

Comment: @shahul - The properties you get from `.offset()` are the `top` and `left` positions calculated relative to the document. As J-P demonstrated above, separate methods are required for `width` and `height`.